# Apache POI 3.17 in OSGi

Tags: java, apache-poi, osgi

**Preamble:** I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825944/how-to-use-apache-poi-in-osgi), but it's obviously about an older version of POI, and Apache went contra to every Java standard since then.

**Problem:** My goal is to get POI to work with OSGi. As of now I'm pretty sure that's not possible, but maybe one of you guys has a good idea. What I tried so far:

**1) Bundling the JARs**

The easiest would be to add bundle information directly to the POI jars (the other answer has details on how to do that). This cannot work, because the JARs export the same packages, e.g. *poi-3.17.jar* and *poi-ooxml-3.17.jar* both export `org.apache.poi`, which is not allowed in OSGi (and in standard Java it's a best practice to have separate packages, too).

**2) Using a prepackaged plug-in**

I found `org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi`, which was created by someone with no understanding of how OSGi works (maybe the Apache guys?). It contains wonky dependencies that are not present in any of the JARs, and especially the import package `org.junit` worries me.

I could not get it to work, since not all the necessary imports are bundles, yet. And since the bundle was so obviously broken I gave it up quickly.

**3) Using a Plug-in with lib folder**

It's really hard to find the correct import and export packages. Ultimately this fails because the POI JARs export standard packages (like `javax.xml` from `xmlbeans`).

**4) Copying the sources to plug-ins**

This is probably my favorite. When you copy the sources into their own plug-ins you get **compile errors**. The JAR *poi-ooxml-3.17.jar* needs a class named `org.etsi.uri.x01903.v13.SignaturePolicyIdType`. The class is contained in *poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar*, but the disturbing truth is its name is `SignaturePolicyIdentifierType`.

**5) Asking Apache**

There is a question "Can POI be used with OSGI?" [in the FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1029C):

> *Starting with POI 3.16 there's a workaround for OSGIs context classloader handling, i.e. it replaces the threads current context classloader with an implementation of limited class view. This will lead to IllegalStateExceptions, as xmlbeans can't find the xml schema definitions in this reduced view. The workaround is to initialize the classloader delegate of POIXMLTypeLoader , which defaults to the current thread context classloader. The initialization should take place before any other OOXML related calls. The class in the example could be any class, which is part of the poi-ooxml-schema or ooxml-schema:*
>   `POIXMLTypeLoader.setClassLoader(CTTable.class.getClassLoader());`

I've not tried it, because it does not make any sense for me: How did they even get their non-standard-conform JARs into bundles? And how would setting the classloader AFTER the class was loaded even help?

**Question:** Is there any way to get the current POI to work with OSGi?

**Note:** I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063336/how-to-create-a-working-osgi-bundle-for-apache-poi-3-8), but it's for an even older version of POI. But obviously it's an ongoing problem.

Comment: I agree with your angriness about the dependency mess of `apache poi`. But to your point 4: `org.etsi.uri.x01903.v13.SignaturePolicyIdType` and `org.etsi.uri.x01903.v13.SignaturePolicyIdentifierType` are two different classes. Both are contained in `ooxml-security-1.1.jar`. So for compiling the package `org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.facets` that jar also is needed in class path.

Comment: I have introduced the `setClassLoader` method initially as I tried to find a way around the disjunct classpath of OSGi - and yes, I didn't know and probably still don't know much about OSGi ... In the meantime, this method is obsolete, as the class-/loader from the given Xmlbeans type is used. I've also used my own servicemix bundle, because the one existed at that time was a mess. If you want this to be fixed in 4.0.0 (Java 8), you might want to get into contact with me ...

Comment: @steffi-s as 4.0.0 is due to be released and I haven't heard from you, have you tried with a nightly? does it work?

Comment: @kiwiwings Sorry, there was no time for experiments. We switched to [SmartXLS](http://www.smartxls.com/indexj.htm) which works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by building my own 3.17 OSGi bundle, which i've dropped in Virgo /repository/usr:

```
<project ..>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.1.7</version>

<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>OSGi-wrapped poi-ooxml</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.virtuald</groupId>
        <artifactId>curvesapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.04</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>org.apache.poi.*</Export-Package>
                    <!--
                    One important thing to note: if you are not exporting a package, you add it to the Private-Package instruction.
                    Otherwise, the classes inside the package will not be copied to your bundle, as the default value of this instruction is empty.
                    -->
                    <Private-Package>org.openxmlformats.*,org.apache.commons.*,com.graphbuilder.curve.*,org.apache.xmlbeans.*,schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.*,schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel.*</Private-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then in my calling code, I create a thread and use the parent classloader.  Would like to hear a better way - this is not trivial to setup.  Would be nice if Apache had OSGi bundles.  I may have extra or missing steps, but am generating Excel files with this code:

```
public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException {

    Runnable sheetCreator = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Workbook workbook = null;
            try {
                // 3.16, but now obsolete
                // POIXMLTypeLoader.setClassLoader(CTTable.class.getClassLoader());
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                buildWorkbook(workbook);
                workbook.write(out);
                out.flush();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // log
            } finally {
                if (workbook != null) {
                    try {
                        workbook.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // log
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    try {
        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        ClassLoader cl = thread.getContextClassLoader();

        Thread th = new Thread(sheetCreator);

        th.setContextClassLoader(cl.getParent());
        th.start();
        th.join();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // log
    }
}
```